# How to access polymer properties in observer function

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

When I try to wrap 'progressbar.js' in a polymer element I can't access circleprop.

```
var startColor = '#FC5B3F';
var endColor = '#6FD57F';

Polymer({
  is: "home-view",
  properties: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      observer: '_valueChanged'
    },
    circleProp: {
      type: Object,
      notify: true,
     reflectToAttribute: true
    }
  },

  ready: function() {
    var element = this.$$('#circleValue');
    this.circleProp = new ProgressBar.Circle(element, {
      color: startColor,
      trailColor: '#eee',
      trailWidth: 1,
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'easeInOut',
      strokeWidth: 5,
      text: {
          value: '0'
      },

      // Set default step function for all animate calls
      step: function(state, circle) {
          circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
          circle.setText((circle.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
      }
  });

  this.circleProp.animate(0.3, {
      from: {color: startColor},
      to: {color: endColor}
  });
},

attach : function() {
  if (this.circleProp) {
      this.circleProp.animate(this.value, {
          from: {color: startColor},
          to: {color: endColor}
      });
  }
},

_valueChanged : function(oldValue, newValue) {
  if (this.circleProp) {
    this.circleProp.animate(newValue, {
        from: {color: startColor},
        to: {color: endColor}
    });
  }
}
});
```

How can I access circleProp so I can do my animation. Or how can I access objects in _valueChanged? It is only possible to access the DOM of this element.

Comment: you should be able to access using `this` keyword, checkout [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#change-callbacks) out.

Comment: _valueChanged is probably run before ready, Polymer is weird like that.
Try to run it manually from the console and  put a console.log(this.circleProp) in it to see whats going on

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the reflectToAttribute on the `circleProp` property.  Why are you doing it?  Polymer is trying to serialize it to the attribute on your element in the dom.

Accessing `this.circleProp` would otherwise work

Comment: when I removed that from the code it was also not working, when doing a console.log of this it prints out a 'DOM' element.

Comment: this.circleProp is undefined ... it looks like _changedValue looses his context and is only bind to the Dom element itself

Answer (score 0):

_valueChanged is definitly called before ready. try an complex observer

```
observers: ['_valueCahnged(value)']
```

This will prevent that the observed value is undefined. Also when writing into properties use

```
this.set('circleProp', newValue)
```

Otherwise Polymer won´t notice that there was an change. Within the _valueCahnged observer you can access all Properties via this